# Is it possible to enter password for SecurePad plugin in Notepad++ using Windows cmd? [edited]

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, command-prompt

I initially planned on making a program that amends a text file which contains valuable data, based on arguments passed from cmd. However, if the text file is left in the open, it kind of negates the use of the program. I know I can use some file encryption tool, but since I would pass command line arguments to the program, it would be easier if I could first decrypt the text from cmd. Is there a method to do so?

Comment: Show research/work/effort you have put into this prior to asking this question.

Comment: I hope I have been able to explain my thought process well now @Alex

Comment: The question is still quite unclear. Are you trying to access the plugin from `batch` or are you trying to use `cmd` to encrypt text/data files?

Comment: Before passing the arguments for the program, I would like to decrypt the previously encrypted text file(using SecurePad plugin) from the cmd itself. Is that possible?